# Running Java 9 module using Log4j2 2.10.0

Tags: java, log4j2, java-9, java-module

I am trying to run a Java 9 module I've created which uses Log4j2 2.10.0.

The problem I'm running into is that I get a

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
```

when doing a `LogManager.getLogger()`. It finds the LogManager class fine, but when it get to the `new PropertiesUtil("log4j2.StatusLogger.properties")` call from inside `StatusLogger`, it gets the above error.

How do fix/find a workaround for this?

Added Info:

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j/org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j/org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:60)
    at com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.Utilities/com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.Utilities.Base.DebugAble.<clinit>(DebugAble.java:45)
```

One more odd thing I can directly call the  invoke: `new PropertiesUtil("string")` from my code and it finds the class.

I am using eclipse oxygen 4.7.1a.

My eclipse launch config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
<setAttribute key="name.schedenig.eclipse.grepconsole.DisabledIds"/>
<setAttribute key="name.schedenig.eclipse.grepconsole.EnabledIds"/>
<setAttribute key="name.schedenig.eclipse.grepconsole.FilterDisabledIds"/>
<setAttribute key="name.schedenig.eclipse.grepconsole.FilterEnabledIds"/>
<setAttribute key="name.schedenig.eclipse.grepconsole.StatisticsDisabledIds"/>
<setAttribute key="name.schedenig.eclipse.grepconsole.StatisticsEnabledIds"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/Evolver/src/com/EvolutionarySoftwareSystems/Evolver/Server/EvolServer.java"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="1"/>
</listAttribute>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.source_locator_id" value="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceLocator.JavaSourceLookupDirector"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.source_locator_memento" value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;sourceLookupDirector&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;sourceContainers duplicates=&quot;false&quot;&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;container memento=&quot;&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot; standalone=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;lt;javaProject name=&amp;quot;EvolGrammarJava&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&quot; typeId=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceContainer.javaProject&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;container memento=&quot;&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot; standalone=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;lt;javaProject name=&amp;quot;Evolver&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&quot; typeId=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceContainer.javaProject&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;container memento=&quot;&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot; standalone=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;lt;javaProject name=&amp;quot;Base&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&quot; typeId=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceContainer.javaProject&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;container memento=&quot;&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot; standalone=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;lt;classpathContainer path=&amp;quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&quot; typeId=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceContainer.classpathContainer&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;container memento=&quot;&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot; standalone=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;lt;javaProject name=&amp;quot;Annotations&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&quot; typeId=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceContainer.javaProject&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;container memento=&quot;&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot; standalone=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;lt;javaProject name=&amp;quot;Utilities&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&quot; typeId=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceContainer.javaProject&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;container memento=&quot;&amp;lt;?xml version=&amp;quot;1.0&amp;quot; encoding=&amp;quot;UTF-8&amp;quot; standalone=&amp;quot;no&amp;quot;?&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&amp;lt;default/&amp;gt;&amp;#13;&amp;#10;&quot; typeId=&quot;org.eclipse.debug.core.containerType.default&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/sourceContainers&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/sourceLookupDirector&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ATTR_USE_START_ON_FIRST_THREAD" value="true"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.Evolver.Server.EvolServer"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MODULEPATH">
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry path=&quot;4&quot; projectName=&quot;Evolver&quot; type=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER&quot; javaProject=&quot;Base&quot; path=&quot;4&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry path=&quot;4&quot; projectName=&quot;Annotations&quot; type=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry path=&quot;4&quot; projectName=&quot;Base&quot; type=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry path=&quot;4&quot; projectName=&quot;Utilities&quot; type=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry path=&quot;4&quot; projectName=&quot;EvolGrammarJava&quot; type=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/antlr/antlr-runtime-4.7.jar&quot; path=&quot;4&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/xerces/xerces-2_11_0/xercesImpl.jar&quot; path=&quot;4&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/log4j2/apache-log4j-2.10.0-bin/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar&quot; path=&quot;4&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/apache/commons-lang3-3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar&quot; path=&quot;4&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/Evolver/Log4j2Config&quot; path=&quot;4&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
</listAttribute>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS" value="C:\eclipseWorkspace\evolver\src\Samples\S_01.evo"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="Evolver"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

The module file:

```
module com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.Evolver {
    //
    // // Export the com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems package
    //
    requires com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.Base;
    requires com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.Utilities;
    requires com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems;
    requires java.base;
    requires java.xml;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires transitive xercesImpl;

    //
    exports com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.Evolver;

    //
    // provides com.EvolutionarySoftwareSystems.LsysEx.App.Main;
}
```

Comment: Please share the module-info that is in use. Dependencies(maven/gradle) in use and the steps used to execute when you get the above error.

Comment: edited above to add information

Comment: possibly related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2129

Answer (score 6):

Log4j has an issue there which is reported at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2129.
Either use 2.9, or use 2.10 with the workaround I provided in that ticket or use 2.11 which was released a couple of days ago and fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. It also  fixed my issue. I was getting failing Jenkins unit tests. This was the error: 

Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

Stacktrace

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

Standard Error

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.  

The fix was to update log4j-api from 2.10.0 to  2.11.2.