# Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil while using Powermock

Tags: log4j2, powermock

While upgrading from log4j1 to log4j2,when easymock is trying to create a mock object it goes through the PowerMock mock control gateway.

PowerMock which hits log4j issue as caused by:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.

Can anyone has thoughts on this how to resolve this? Thanks..

Comment: I face the same issue - did you get a resolution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Java 9 module using Log4j2 2.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521726/running-java-9-module-using-log4j2-2-10-0)